# BASH SHELL: Using awk, with a delimiter, 2 search terms

Tags: bash, shell, search, delimiter

I'm very new to BASH Shell programming. Here's my issue, I need to split data from my file (with a semicolon delimiter) and search if a certain book exists.

file contents:

```
Harry Potter - The Half Blood Prince:J.K Rowling:40.30:10:50
The little Red Riding Hood:Dan Lin:40.80:20:10
Harry Potter - The Phoniex:J.K Rowling:50.00:30:20
Harry Potter - The Deathly Hollow:Dan Lin:55.00:33:790
Little Prince:The Prince:15.00:188:9
Lord of The Ring:Johnny Dept:56.80:100:38
Three Little Pig:Andrew Lim:89.10:290:189
All About Ubuntu:Ubuntu Team:76.00:55:133
Catch Me If You Can:Mary Ann:23.60:6:2
Happy Day:Mary Ann:12.99:197:101
Harry:Potter
asd:dsa
Harry:Potter
```

My code here:

```
read -p "Title: " addtitle
read -p "Author: " addauthor
#check if book exists

awk '{
if ($1=="$addtitle" && $2=="$addauthor")
print $0, "found";
else
  print $0, "Not found";
}' BooksDB.txt
```

when I run my code, it gives me:

```
Title: Harry
Author: Potter
Harry Potter - The Half Blood Prince:J.K Rowling:40.30:10:50 Not found
The little Red Riding Hood:Dan Lin:40.80:20:10 Not found
Harry Potter - The Phoniex:J.K Rowling:50.00:30:20 Not found
Harry Potter - The Deathly Hollow:Dan Lin:55.00:33:790 Not found
Little Prince:The Prince:15.00:188:9 Not found
Lord of The Ring:Johnny Dept:56.80:100:38 Not found
Three Little Pig:Andrew Lim:89.10:290:189 Not found
All About Ubuntu:Ubuntu Team:76.00:55:133 Not found
Catch Me If You Can:Mary Ann:23.60:6:2 Not found
Happy Day:Mary Ann:12.99:197:101 Not found
Harry:Potter Not found
asd:dsa Not found
Harry:Potter Not found
```

instead of what I want:

```
Harry:Potter found
Harry:Potter found
```

I'm not so sure if it might be due to the delimter to use awk -f "[:] but I'm don't know how to incorporate into my code..

Answer (score 0):

Pass your custom *title* and *author* values as a variables to **`awk`** program:

```
awk -F':' -v title="Harry" -v author="Potter" '$1==title && $2==author{ print $0,"found" }' file
```

The output:

```
Harry:Potter found
Harry:Potter found
```